# Excel 2013, making a titration curve

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I have to make a titration curve of adding 12 times 1 ml of acid to a buffer solution and doing this again by adding a base to the same buffer solution, with the measured pH-value on the vertical axis.

The problem I have is with the horizontal axis, I'm required to have te axis go from 12 mL to 0, and then again from 0 to 12 (with 0 being in the center of the horizontal axis and on both the left and right end 12). The curve that shows the pH value by adding acid has to go from the left part of the horizontal axis and the curve when adding base to the solution has to go from 0 to 12 on the right of the horizontal axis.

I hope this paint drawing makes it more clear:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZhlt.jpg

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm guessing you mean i have to go in this menu, but i can't click edit, or am i wrong? http://imgur.com/uTIwqCT

Comment: Yes, this is the right place - strange, try to start Excel as Admin!

Comment: I figured it out, had something to do with the type of curve i chose but after choosing a different type of curve it works! Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a 2D-Graph as usually, then right-clicked set the data values for the X axis manually, in my example e.g. to **A2:A26**:

[image]